# TouchAction class in appium is asking for parameters such as <T extends TouchActions> could someone go example of how to instantiate it

Tags: java, appium

I used to do it like this:
TouchAction t = new TouchAction (driver);

But now  is asking me for generics!
Also some methods deprecated, could some one give me an example of how to instantiate TouchAction class in appium with java please?

Comment: Could you post the relevant code (as formatted code), and the error you are getting on your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have selected wrong package for TouchAction:

import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.TouchAction;

Instead, you should use :

import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply call the constructor without any parameters, for example :

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
```

If you are getting errors you might be missing some dependencies or have errors elsewhere in your code. Do you have the correct appiumDrivers available? More information can be found here : https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.html

Answer (score 0):

Import TouchAction class, While using the 1st Initialization you might get warning like --raw use of parameterized class 'touchaction'--, but It will not effect anything on test running. To removethe warning you can use 2nd statement. <?> is used to indicate some unknown type. It can accept anytype.

```
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

1. TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
 Or 
2. TouchAction<?> touchAction = new TouchAction<>(driver);
```